# How to use ebean-spring with SpringBoot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, ebean

I want to use SpringBoot with Ebean. I found this article: http://ebean-orm.github.io/docs/setup/spring and I could set it up and make it work with an own implementation of a EbeanServerFactory as shown in the article.

It states, that if I add ebean-spring to my dependencies along with a default-ebean-server.xml than it should work with a default EbeanServerFactoryBean. But what should I write to this file? Where do I set up the FactoryBean to use my datasource etc.? Sorry if my question is silly, but I am really new to SpringBoot and don't understand it deeply.

If I add ebean-spring and remove my own factory I get an error:

```
No qualifying bean of type [com.avaje.ebean.EbeanServer] found for dependency
```

Comment: Hi you can see working EBean configuration with Spring Boot for example here https://github.com/bwajtr/java-persistence-frameworks-comparison

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I could solve it after a day of thinking, and trying. In Spring you usually have an Application.java or something which starts your app with your main(). Here you can define a EbeanServer Factory like the following:

```
@Bean
public EbeanServerFactoryBean ebeanServerFactoryBean() {
    EbeanServerFactoryBean ebeanServerFactoryBean = new EbeanServerFactoryBean();
    ServerConfig config = new ServerConfig();

    config.setName("pg");
    config.loadFromProperties();
    //other configs
    config.setDefaultServer(true);

    ebeanServerFactoryBean.setServerConfig(config);
    return ebeanServerFactoryBean;
}
```

Comment: Working example of EBean + SpringBoot for example here: https://github.com/bwajtr/java-persistence-frameworks-comparison